# Checking if there is an active internet connection iPhone situation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reachability, internet-connection

I would like to check to see if the user has an active internet connection. This is how I have implemented it. It seems to work fine but the problem is it ALWAYS shows that there is no connection on my iPhone simulator (uialert comes up) even when my wifi is turned on or off. Does any know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

```
Reachability *r= [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus= [r currentReachabilityStatus];

 if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN))
    {

        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No internet" message:@"No internet connection found. Please try again later"
                                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

 else {

 // execute code in app

 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I have done it in my apps:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *errorView;

    errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Network error", @"Network error")
                 message: NSLocalizedString(@"No internet connection found, this application requires an internet connection to gather the data required.", @"Network error")
                 delegate: self
                 cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"Network error") otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [errorView show];
    [errorView autorelease];
}
```

What is does is that it checks for an internetconnection, not if it can reach a domain. If no internet connection (wifi or celluar) it will show an UIAlertView message (localized).

Answer (score 0):

Don't check.  The radio often starts turning on and establishing a connection just after reachability reports no network (the reachability reporting that there is no network may be what starts this process and thus renders it's own answer to be false a few seconds later.)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by the "radio"? And I have heard from past users that if you do not check, the app store will reject?

Comment: I've had three Apps approved by the app store that all required network activity and I researched this quite a bit. you don't have to check reachability details if you don't want to, and I suspect most apps do not. However, you DO need to have user-friendly behavior in your app if it requires network but network is not present. this means no freezes, hangs, and most definitely show an Alert or similar if the app needs internet but it is not available.